# SwiftyJson adding to end of object/Array

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have a SwiftyJSON object representing questions and answers, fetched as JSON from a webserver.

What i would like to achieve, is to add questions to the end of the SwiftyJSON object, taken that the user answers the question wrongly.

I've tried the following

```
JsonArray[ JsonArray.count+1 ] = JsonArray[CurrentIndex]
```

But nothing happens at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surprisingly simple:

`let data = JSON(currentdata.arrayObject! + newdata.arrayObject!)`